# WSO2 remotely adding/removing new OSGI features

Tags: wso2, osgi, wso2-identity-server

Is there a working example available to remotely add AND remove OSGI Features to WSO2 carbon based products via the ProvisioningAdminService SOAP interface?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to have WSO2 Carbon binary distribution when you need to add or remove OSGi bundle,
Then start with following command in WSO2 carbon Server.

`sh wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole` or
`./wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole` 

After starting up the server click the enter button two to three time and then start with `osgi>` console.
Now you can install/remove osgi bundle.

```
start <bundle-id> (Ex: osgi> start 22)
```

This command can be used to start a osgi bundle.

```
install file:<file-path> [Ex: osgi> install file:/home/yourname/osgibundle.jar]
```

This can be used to install a bundle into a running OSGi environment. You can use this command to install your bundle, instead of copying it into dropping folder prior to starting the server. After installing, use 'start' command to activate the bundle.

```
uninstall <bundle-id> [Ex: osgi> uninstall 22]
```

This can be used to remove a bundle from the OSGi environment.

You can refer the below links and try with WSO2 products.
.......................................
[OSGi bundle](http://wso2.com/library/articles/getting-started-wso2-carbon/) 
[Admin Services](http://techspiro.blogspot.com/2015/01/wso2-admin-services-and-admin-services.html)